# Error while Return data frame as list PySpark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Im encountering error when Im trying to return data frame as list from my user defined function

```
myDataFrame = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (10001, "2017-02-12 12:01:40" , "2017-02-12 12:56:32"),
        (10001, "2017-02-13 12:06:32" , "2017-02-15 16:06:32"),
        (10001, "2017-02-16 21:45:56" , "2017-02-21 21:45:56"),
        (10001, "2017-02-21 22:32:41" , "2017-02-25 00:52:50"),
        ]).toDF(["id",  "startTime" ,  "endTime"]).withColumn("startTime", col("startTime").cast("timestamp")).withColumn("endTime", col("endTime").cast("timestamp")))


return_type = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
@udf(returnType=return_type)
def myUdf(start, end):
  start = pd.to_datetime(start,infer_datetime_format=True)
  end = pd.to_datetime(end,infer_datetime_format=True)
  rng = pd.date_range(start.floor('h'), end.floor('h'), freq='h')
  left = pd.Series(rng, index=rng).clip_lower(start)
  right = pd.Series(rng + 1, index=rng).clip_upper(end)
  timeSeries = right - left
  resultDataFrame = []
  for key, result in timeSeries.items():
    resultDataFrame.append((datetime.weekday(key.date()) , key.time().hour , int(result.total_seconds()//60)))
  resultDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(resultDataFrame, columns=('day', 'hour', 'minute'))
  response = resultDataFrame.to_dict("index").values()
  return (list(response))


extracted = myUdf("startTime", "endTime")
exploded = explode(extracted).alias("exploded")
expanded = [col("exploded").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in ["day", "hour", "minute"]]
result = myDataFrame.select("id", exploded).select("id",*expanded)
result.show()
```

I want to print result like this

```
+---------+----+----+------+                                                         
|utilityId|day |hour|minute|
+---------+----+----+------+
```

But, I get error like

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1005.0 (TID 18845)
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:155)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a list of dictionaries of numpy type objects which is not a supported type by pyspark.

```py
type(list(response)[0]['day'])

    numpy.int64
```

Using "2017-02-13 12:06:32" , "2017-02-15 16:06:32" as `start` and `end` your function returns:

```py
    +-----+------+-------+--------+
    |     | day  | hour  | minute |
    +-----+------+-------+--------+
    |  0  |   0  |   12  |     53 |
    |  1  |   0  |   13  |     60 |
    |  2  |   0  |   14  |     60 |
    |  3  |   0  |   15  |     60 |
    |  4  |   0  |   16  |     60 |
    |  5  |   0  |   17  |     60 |
    |  6  |   0  |   18  |     60 |
    |  7  |   0  |   19  |     60 |
    |  8  |   0  |   20  |     60 |
    |  9  |   0  |   21  |     60 |
    | 10  |   0  |   22  |     60 |
    | 11  |   0  |   23  |     60 |
    | 12  |   1  |    0  |     60 |
    | 13  |   1  |    1  |     60 |
    | 14  |   1  |    2  |     60 |
    | 15  |   1  |    3  |     60 |
    | 16  |   1  |    4  |     60 |
    | 17  |   1  |    5  |     60 |
    | 18  |   1  |    6  |     60 |
    | 19  |   1  |    7  |     60 |
    | 20  |   1  |    8  |     60 |
    | 21  |   1  |    9  |     60 |
    | 22  |   1  |   10  |     60 |
    | 23  |   1  |   11  |     60 |
    | 24  |   1  |   12  |     60 |
    | 25  |   1  |   13  |     60 |
    | 26  |   1  |   14  |     60 |
    | 27  |   1  |   15  |     60 |
    | 28  |   1  |   16  |     60 |
    | 29  |   1  |   17  |     60 |
    | 30  |   1  |   18  |     60 |
    | 31  |   1  |   19  |     60 |
    | 32  |   1  |   20  |     60 |
    | 33  |   1  |   21  |     60 |
    | 34  |   1  |   22  |     60 |
    | 35  |   1  |   23  |     60 |
    | 36  |   2  |    0  |     60 |
    | 37  |   2  |    1  |     60 |
    | 38  |   2  |    2  |     60 |
    | 39  |   2  |    3  |     60 |
    | 40  |   2  |    4  |     60 |
    | 41  |   2  |    5  |     60 |
    | 42  |   2  |    6  |     60 |
    | 43  |   2  |    7  |     60 |
    | 44  |   2  |    8  |     60 |
    | 45  |   2  |    9  |     60 |
    | 46  |   2  |   10  |     60 |
    | 47  |   2  |   11  |     60 |
    | 48  |   2  |   12  |     60 |
    | 49  |   2  |   13  |     60 |
    | 50  |   2  |   14  |     60 |
    | 51  |   2  |   15  |     60 |
    | 52  |   2  |   16  |      6 |
    +-----+------+-------+--------+
```

We can construct the date range in hours and derive the other columns from it:

```py
import datetime as dt
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, TimestampType
date_range_udf = psf.udf(
    lambda start, end: [start + dt.timedelta(hours=x) 
                         for x in range(0, int((end.replace(second=0,minute=0) - start.replace(second=0,minute=0)).total_seconds())//3600 + 1)], 
    ArrayType(TimestampType()))

myDataFrame_range = myDataFrame \
    .withColumn("date", psf.explode(date_range_udf("startTime", "endTime")))
myDataFrame_range.show()

    +-----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
    |   id|          startTime|            endTime|               date|
    +-----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
    |10001|2017-02-12 12:01:40|2017-02-12 12:56:32|2017-02-12 12:01:40|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 12:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 13:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 14:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 15:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 16:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 17:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 18:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 19:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 20:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 21:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 22:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-13 23:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 00:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 01:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 02:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 03:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 04:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 05:06:32|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|2017-02-14 06:06:32|
    +-----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Now for the other columns:

```py
myDataFrame_range \
    .select(
        'id', 'startTime', 'endTime', 
        (psf.from_unixtime(psf.unix_timestamp('date'), 'u') - 1).cast('int').alias('day'), 
        psf.hour('date').alias('hour'), 
        psf.when(
                psf.col('startTime') == psf.col('date'), 
                60 - psf.minute('startTime') - (psf.second('startTime') > 0).cast('int')) \
            .when(
                ((psf.unix_timestamp('endTime') - psf.unix_timestamp('date'))/3600).cast("int") == 0, 
                psf.minute('startTime')) \
            .otherwise(60).alias('minute')) \
    .show()

    +-----+-------------------+-------------------+---+----+------+
    |   id|          startTime|            endTime|day|hour|minute|
    +-----+-------------------+-------------------+---+----+------+
    |10001|2017-02-12 12:01:40|2017-02-12 12:56:32|  6|  12|    58|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  12|    53|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  13|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  14|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  15|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  16|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  17|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  18|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  19|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  20|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  21|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  22|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  0|  23|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   0|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   1|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   2|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   3|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   4|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   5|    60|
    |10001|2017-02-13 12:06:32|2017-02-15 16:06:32|  1|   6|    60|
    +-----+-------------------+-------------------+---+----+------+
```

It's better to avoid using `UDF` as much as possible, keep in mind that `pyspark.sql.functions` are optimized for computation.

Comment: `
myDataFrame = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (10001, "2017-02-12 12:25:00" , "2017-02-12 13:14:00"),
        ]).toDF(["id",  "startTime" ,  "endTime"]).
        withColumn("startTime", col("startTime").cast("timestamp")).
        withColumn("endTime", col("endTime").cast("timestamp")))' For this data I suppose to get 35 mns in first row which is OK but second row I dont get that is Hour 13 - 14 mns. However if the minute is > start times minute it looks OK.

Comment: You're right `endTime` and `date` are only equal at an hour precision. I modified my answer for it to work

Comment: `"2017-02-12 12:40:40" , "2017-02-12 12:53:32" and "2017-02-12 12:40:40" , "2017-02-13 12:23:32" ` these dates has issue. It is generating right result.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: If I give `"2017-02-12 12:40:40" , "2017-02-12 13:02:40"` as start and end time I should get 19 mns for 12 hrs and 02 mns for 13 hrs. But i get only for 12 hrs not for 13 hrs.

Comment: This should do it: I modified the `UDF` to have a timedelta in hours between dates rounded to the nearest hour. Could you please provide a full sample data set with the desired output next time.